# Is there a way to make pairs from 2 different arrays that also have different sizes?

Tags: arrays, c, strcat

So I have 2 different sized arrays and I want to pair elements from them into a new one.

Example:

a = {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}

b = {a b c d}

c = {1a 1b 1c 1d 2a 2b 2c 2d...9a 9b 9c 9d}(The array I want to obtain)

So far I've got this, and it prints as follows: 1a 1ab 1abc...

I've managed to print them in the way I want with `printf("%s%s", &a[i], &b[j])` but I still can't wrap my head on how to save this pairs in a separate array

```
    const char *a[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    const char *b[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    char *f;

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j ++){
            f = (strcat(&a[i], &b[j]));
            printf("%s ", f);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to learn C and I hit a wall at this part. Thank you for understanding and sorry if my english is bad

Comment: You will need a third array, and make your second loop flexble enough to increase the index independently from the first loop. I will post the answer above.

Comment: So what you really want is an `M x N`array.

Comment: Should the arrays contain characters or should they contain strings?

Comment: From my understanding I want to access each pair as a single element in the list: 1a to be an element, 1b another and so on. I don't really know exactly what type this would be. Sorry if I am vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Character arrays

If arrays `a` and `b` only contain characters, you don't even need the function `strcat`. I have provided example code in which array `f` contains nine strings with two characters plus the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) `'\0'` each.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    /* arrays `a` and `b` only contain characters */
    char a[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    char b[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

    /* array `f` contains 9 * 4 strings with 3 characters each */
    char f[9 * 4][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            int k = i * 4 + j;
            f[k][0] = a[i];
            f[k][1] = b[j];
            /* null character for string termination */
            f[k][2] = '\0';
        }
    }

    /* print content of the array `f` */
    for (int k = 0; k < 9 * 4; ++k)
            printf("%s ", f[k]);
    printf("\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After compiling, the first program outputs the following when executed:

```sh
1a 1b 1c 1d 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a 3b 3c 3d 4a 4b 4c 4d 5a 5b 5c 5d 6a 6b 6c 6d 7a 7b 7c 7d 8a 8b 8c 8d 9a 9b 9c 9d
```

### String arrays

If arrays `a` and `b` are supposed to contain strings with more than one character, you will need to use `strcpy` and `strcat` from `<string.h>`. Choose an appropriate maximum size for the strings in `f`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    /* arrays `a` and `b` contain strings with multiple character */
    char *a[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    char *b[] = {"_a", "_b", "_c", "_d"};

    /* array `f` contains 9 * 4 strings with a maximum of 15 characters*/
    char f[9 * 4][15];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            int k = i * 4 + j;
            strcpy(f[k], a[i]);
            /* `strcat` automatically null-terminates */
            strcat(f[k], b[j]);
        }
    }

    /* print content of the array `f` */
    for (int k = 0; k < 9 * 4; ++k)
            printf("%s ", f[k]);
    printf("\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After compiling, the second program outputs the following when executed:

```sh
one_a one_b one_c one_d two_a two_b two_c two_d three_a three_b three_c three_d four_a four_b four_c four_d five_a five_b five_c five_d six_a six_b six_c six_d seven_a seven_b seven_c seven_d eight_a eight_b eight_c eight_d nine_a nine_b nine_c nine_d
```

Comment: This works, but I still have a problem that I have not stated in my post. I want the end result to work in a linked list. And while trying to use the value of z[i] as my next data value in my list I get get a warning that tells me that I try to make an integer out of a pointer without a cast. Can you also please guide me in this also?

Comment: @Lamor I don't know what your entire code is, but does the second solution work for you then?

Comment: @Lamor If that doesn't solve your problem, add the missing information to your question, because there could be different reasons for the error.

Comment: Yes they both work. Now I just have to find a way to integrate them to my code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about what you need...

If you want an output like this:
`1a 1b 1c 1d 2 2b 2c 2d 3 3b 3c 3d 4 4b 4c 4d 5 5b 5c 5d 6 6b 6c 6d 7 7b 7c 7d 8 8b 8c 8d 9 9b 9c 9d`

The easiest solution is to consider f as an array of two characters.
Because strcat (`char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`) concatenate the 2nd parameter string after the 1st parameter string you can't simply use the fist character as destination but you need a third variable, in your case `f`.

After printing, you have to reinitialize *(with strcpy 'cause it's a string)* it in order to have the space for the next couple.

```c
    const char *a[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    const char *b[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    char f[2] = "";

    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            strcat(f, &a[i]);
            strcat(f, &b[j]);
            printf("%s ",f);
            strcpy(f,"");
        }
    }
```

I hope that it is what you need!

**EDIT** -> to save the values you need a 4th array with size (A*size* x B*size*)

Answer (score 0):

This is good, but still has a bug. I'll fix it right away:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NODE_LEN 2 + 1

void solution() {
    
    const char a[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    const char b[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    char *result_array[8] = { 0 };
    char f[NODE_LEN] = { 0 };
    int i, index_j;

    for (i = 0, index_j = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        
        sprintf(f, "%c%c", a[i], b[index_j]);
        printf("%s ", f);
        
        char* new_value = calloc(NODE_LEN, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(new_value, f);
        result_array[i] = new_value;
        
        if (++index_j >= 4) index_j = 0;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("-%s\n", result_array[i]);
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        free(result_array[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    solution();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually referred to as a *permutation* function. We will need space to store our results, and this will be the length of array `A` times the length of array `B`.

Our individual results will be of type `char [3]`, one space for a number, one for a letter, and one for the NUL terminating byte (`'\0'`) required to properly create a *string* in C.

```
const char a[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
const char b[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

char zipped[9*4][3];

for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++, k++) {
        zipped[k][0] = a[i];
        zipped[k][1] = b[j];
        zipped[k][2] = '\0';
    }

for (int i = 0; i < 9 * 4; i++)
    printf("%s ", zipped[i]);

// 1a 1b 1c 1d 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a 3b 3c 3d 4a 4b 4c 4d 5a 5b 5c 5d 6a 6b 6c 6d 7a 7b 7c 7d 8a 8b 8c 8d 9a 9b 9c 9d
```

Comment: I would print a newline `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To store everything in a separate array, you'll need to either allocate memory through malloc (or similar) or designate a fixed size arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const char a[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    const char b[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    char **f;
    
    // Getting the size of each array
    const int a_size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    const int b_size = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]);

    // Allocating the memory needed for the array of strings
    f = (char**) malloc(a_size * b_size * sizeof(char*));

    for(int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < b_size; j++) {

            // Allocating memory for each combination pair. 1a, 1b...
            f[i * a_size + j] = (char*) malloc(3 * sizeof(char)); // Size of 3 is needed to include the null terminator '\0'
            sprintf(f[i * a_size + j], "%c%c", a[i], b[j]);
            printf("%s ", f[i * a_size + j]);
        }
    }

    // Make sure to free all the allocated memory.
    for (int i = 0; i < a_size * b_size; i++) {
        free(f[i]);
    }
    free(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with `gcc` will output

> 1a 1b 1c 1d 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a 3b 3c 3d 4a 4b 4c 4d 5a 5b 5c 5d 6a 6b 6c 6d 7a 7b 7c 7d 8a 8b 8c 8d 9a 9b 9c 9d

Comment: When I tested this out I got the following error on run time: double free or corruption(out)